# Getting error when removing join using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, error-000800

I have joined a CSV table to a raster layer, now I am trying to remove the join. I have typed the following command:

```
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("hwsd_lyr",hwsd_csv)
```

It gives the following error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of  | HWSD_CLS_DATA.csv.
Failed to execute (RemoveJoin).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified what your `hwsd_csv` value is.  However, you need to use the name of the data source, not the name of the table view when removing a join.

So, based on the values in the error message, perhaps the following might work:

```
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("hwsd_lyr", "HWSD_CLS_DATA")
```

or possibly:

```
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("hwsd_lyr", "HWSD_CLS_DATA.csv")
```

The documentation at [ArcGIS Pro / Tool Reference / Tools / Data Management toolbox / Joins and Relates toolset / Remove Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/remove-join.htm) states:

> The join name will not reflect the name of the table view itself, but rather the source of the table view. Therefore, if a table view is named `TableView1` and points at `mytable.dbf`, the name of the join will be `"mytable"`.

Alternatively, you can just remove all joins by not specifying the join name at all:

```
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("hwsd_lyr")
```

Comment: The last command worked

Comment: In that case, mark as solved. Thanks